# How to set kernel parameters when building a custom android ROM?

Tags: android, linux-kernel, custom-rom, lineageos

I am trying to build a custom ROM on my own. I got hold of the kernel source, android code (LineageOS), device tree and the vendor files. I do a `mka bacon -j8` and am getting this error:

```
In file included from /home/fury/android/lineage/kernel/xiaomi/platina/arch/arm64/kernel/perf_trace_counters.c:16:0:
/home/fury/android/lineage/kernel/xiaomi/platina/include/trace/events/sched.h:875:2: error: #error "Unsupported NR_CPUS for lb tracepoint."
 #error "Unsupported NR_CPUS for lb tracepoint."
```

I can see that the kernel parameter NR_CPUS is being set to an unsupported value somewhere. Where could this be set?

KConfig NR_CPUS section:

```
config NR_CPUS
        int "Maximum number of CPUs (2-4096)"
        range 2 4096
        # These have to remain sorted largest to smallest
        default "64"
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on [android.se]. It's not about programming.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question, the kernel parameters are set in the config files present in

```
kernel/<vendor>/<device>/arch/arm64/configs/
```

folder.

In my case, the parameter is set in the file `platina_user_defconfig` in the above folder, and then this filename is to be specified in the `BoardConfig.mk` file present in the device tree:

```
$ cat device/xiaomi/platina/BoardConfig.mk | grep TARGET_KERNEL_CONFIG
TARGET_KERNEL_CONFIG := platina_user_defconfig
```

I was specifying the wrong filename as `TARGET_KERNEL_CONFIG`, hence I got the error.